# Pointers vs vectors for arrays c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector, memory-management

In the case I am creating an 'array' on stack in c++, is it better to initialise an empty vector with a reserved number of elements and then pass this to a function like `foo()` as a reference as below. Or is it better to set an array `arrb` of size `nelems`, then using a pointer `p_arrb` to the address of the first element increment the pointer and assign some value?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
 
void foo(std::vector<int>& arr){
    int nelems = arr.capacity();    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < nelems; i++){
        arr[i] = i;
    }

}


int main()
{
    
    int nelems; 
    std::cout << "Type a number: "; // Type a number and press enter
    std::cin >> nelems; 

    std::vector<int> arr;
    arr.reserve(nelems); // Init std lib vector
    foo(arr);
    
    int arrb[nelems];
    int* p_arrb = &(arrb[0]);  // pointer to arrb
    
    for (int i = 0; i < nelems; i ++){
        *(p_arrb++) = i;  // populate using pointer
    }
    p_arrb -= nelems; // decrement pointer

    return 0;
}
```

It seems people prefer the use of vector as it is standardised and easier to read? Apart from that, is there any performance benefit to using vector instead of a basic pointer in this case where I do not need to change the size of my vector/array at any point in the code?

Comment: `reserve()` should be `resize()` and `capacity()` should be `size()`

Comment: Using `vector` in this way looks bad because the behavior doesn't look guaranteed. The array way should be better than this usage of `vector` because this should work if the compiler supports that and the number of elements isn't too many. (I personally think simply assigning to each elements of array using index is better because it looks simple and easy to read)

Comment: @MikeCAT why should it. `resize()` allocates memory and creates instances? I do not want to create instances at that point, if the vector is long and I am creating random indexes it is wasteful.

Comment: Then you should use `reserve()` to allocate memory and `emplace_back()` to create instances.

Comment: @Kyle You can certainly `reserve()` a `vector` to pre-allocate its inner array, but if you then manually write directly into the array's memory (which will be *undefined behavior* prior to C++20's implicit object lifetimes), there is no way to tell the `vector` what its new `size()` should be. `reserve()` does not affect the `size()`, and `resize()`'ing to a larger size (since the initial `size()` is 0 if you just `reserve()`) will overwrite with default values what you had already written.

Comment: Ok, so in this case be sure to use `emplace_back()` else `arr.size()` remains 0. From what I have read, I should be using vector here as the size of the array is not known at compile time. The array `arrb` as I have defined it is a variable length array which may cause a stack overflow and should never be used.

Comment: `int arrb[nelems]` where `nelems` is a variable is not valid in standard C++,   Unfortunately, it is a NON-STANDARD extension supported by some compilers (and the documentation for more than one such compiler falsely claims it is standard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `arrb` variant because the size of an array must be a compile-time constant in C++, but you are trying to use a runtime size here.

If your compiler is compiling this, then it is doing so only because it supports these so-called *variable-length arrays* as a non-standard extension. Other compilers will not support them or have differing degree of support or behavior. These arrays are optionally-supported in C, but even there they are probably not worth the trouble they cause.

There is no way to allocate a runtime-dependent amount of memory on the stack in C++ (except if you misuse recursive function calls to simulate it).

So yes, you should use the `vector` approach. But as discussed in the comments under the question, what you are doing is wrong and causes undefined behavior. You need to either `reserve` memory and then `emplace_back`/`push_back` elements into the vector or you need to `resize` the vector to the expected size and then you may index it directly. Indexing a vector outside the the range of elements already created in it causes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

What you should use depends on the exact goal you have. In general the best approach is to avoid using "raw arrays" (both dynamic and static) wherever possible.

If you need dynamic array, use `std::vector`. If you need static array, use `std::array`.